# gps connecting taking time in some android phones

Tags: android, gps

i am using this code to get the latitude and longitude of my current location... but the application is crashing sometimes. On some phones it is taking really long time to get the location while other applications using gps gets location faster on same device

```
package com.example.newproject;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
private TextView tv;
private static LocationManager locationMgr = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    locationMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    try {
        locationMgr.removeUpdates(this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    locationMgr = null;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tv.setText(""+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Update time for LocationUpdates might be dependent on various Conditions e.g. CPU Speed, GPS ChipSet, Your Wifi connection (if using wifi for location) etc. I'd be interested in looking at the crash-log.

Answer (score 0):

First of all You must check if location providers are enabled, for example:

```
boolean networkProviderEnabled=locationMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
boolean gpsProviderEnabled=locationMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Secondly, try to also use network provider for quick but not so accurate location, not only the GPS satellites.

Great tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

Getting a lock on GPS satellites takes time. You can use `getLastKnownLocation` while you wait for a GPS lock, or use `NETWORK_PROVIDER` which is quicker but less precise.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark: the location providers defined in the API constants are not guaranteed to be available. I have experienced crashes with code like this:

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Instead, try selecting a location provider using `LocationManager.getBestProvider()`. This will return a valid location provider or null, if none is available, so test for null before requesting location updates. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider%28android.location.Criteria,%20boolean%29

If for some reason you require GPS, try this code:

```
if (mLocationManager.getAllProviders().indexOf(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) >= 0) {
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
} else {
    Log.w("MainActivity", "No GPS location provider found. Location data will not be available.");
}
```